# How to delete proxy settings from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am configuring flutter first time and getting below mentioned exception.
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

I have firewall configured in my system, because of the security concerns from my organization.
Well, I tried deleting the gradle, build and .idea folders.

Comment: I found my solution on my own :( 
I resolved this issue by not deleting the proxies, but I asked my organization to provide me open IP for some time, and did gradle sync, as soon as I started my gradle sync all my pending gradle files started downloading and I could run my application successfully.